# How to safely replace single slash with double slash in Java, leaving existing double slash untouched?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string which contain a directory path. Value of the string is set from some environment variable. The number of slashes in the string might vary like below (as in sysout).

```
String path = "C:\dirA\dirB\dirC"
```

or

```
String path = "C:\\dirA\\dirB\\dirC"
```

I am expecting `\\` and not `\`. For this, I can try `path.replace('\','\\')` which converts first string to second one. But if the environment variable is already in the format of `C:\\dirA\\dirB\\dirC`, then `path.replace()` will give me `C:\\\\dirA\\\\dirB\\\\dirC`, and I dont want that. So how can I replace `\` with `\\` and leave the existing `\\` in the string?

Comment: What should happen with 3 or more backslashes?

Comment: Your first line of code isn't valid. You only need double backslashes inside a string literal or a regular expression. These are neither. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP i have already mentioned that it is as in sysout. They are not real variables, and i know very well that a surfing should not contain single slashes

Comment: I wonder why -1

Comment: What does 'as in sysout' mean? And 'not real variables'?

Comment: @EJP as in System.out.println() . When the variable is printed in console. Not real variable means, in a variable, \qw\er\ty cannot be saved and it should be in the format qw\\er\\ty with escape \. Thats why said not real variables

Comment: I don't understand a word of that. Try again. I suspect an XY problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `path.replaceAll('\\\\+','\\\\\\\\')`

Comment: I thought OP want to "leave the existing \\ in the string"? But your code will replace any amount of \ with \\.

Comment: @Robert Yes Robert, was in the process of doing it.

Comment: @lexicore Yes, but for the use case it's sufficient.

Comment: @MuratK. You want to say `"C:\dirA\dirB\dirC"` will be converted to `""C:\\dirA\\dirB\\dirC""` and `"C:\\dirA\\dirB\\dirC"` will be left as is? I highly doubt it.

Comment: @AsifAli72090 How does it not provide an answer to the question?

Comment: you should explain your answer in detail so that new users can also be .helped

Comment: @AsifAli72090 the level of detail of an answer contains has nothing to do with it being an answer or not. I suggest you read the review guidelines again

Answer (score 1):

In java source, inside double quotes a backslash is the start of an escape sequence, like `\n` is a newline character. The backslash char itself is written as `\\` but compiled to a single backslash.

Hence

```
String path = "C:\nA\nB\nC";
```

does not refer to a directory nA but is a string with 4 lines.

Correct would have been:

```
String path = "C:\\nA\\nB\\nC";
String path = "C:/nA/nB/nC";
```

The second version POSIX compliant, compatible with Linux and MacOS and others.

You would need to repair an incorrect string as:

```
path = path.replace("\n", "\\n") // Line Feed (char)10
    .replace("\r", "\\r")        // Carriage return (char)13
    .replace("\t", "\\t")        // Tab (char)9
    .replace("\f", "\\f");       // Form Feed (char)12
```

And so on. Numeric sequences like `\u0041` (`'A'`) cannot possibly be reconstructed.

In non-java you can do:

```
path = path.replace("\\\\", "\\"); // Replace any double backslashes to one again.
path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\"); // Double all single backslashes.
```

Comment: Why are you talking about `\n` - it's not in the question?

Comment: @lexicore in the question is `\d` but `d`stands for any directory name's initial. I used `\n` as that is a valid and more known escape sequence.

Comment: I am sorry, I really don't understand. The question how I see it is about replacing single backslashes (`\`) with double (`\\`) and leaving double backslashes alone. What does it have to do with escape sequences?

Comment: `"a\nb"` has **no backslash** in it; it contains 3 chars: 'a', 10, 'b'.

Comment: I still see no relevance. The OP clearly wants to process backslashes.

Comment: @lexicore the OP is misunderstanding what he has in the string; or he is processing a java source. `"a\\nb"` has **one backslash**, with 4 chars: `'a', '\\'` (one backslash), `'n', 'b'`

Comment: @lexicore Sorry, reread the question and simply the code part might be mistaken. At the end after "In non-Java you can do" was code for doubling backslashes. _It could very well be, you are right._

Comment: Ok, glad we cleared that out. :) I was worried I'm missing something obvious.